# Consuming SQL Server data events for messaging purposes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, rabbitmq

At our organization we have a SQL Server 2005 database and a fair number of database clients: web sites (php, zope, asp.net), rich clients (legacy fox pro). Now we need to pass certain events from the core database with other systems (MongoDb, LDAP and others). Messaging paradigm seems pretty capable of solving this kind of problem. So we decided to use RabbitMQ broker as a middleware.

The problem of consuming events from the database at first seemed to have only two possible solutions:

1. Poll the database for outgoing messages and pass them to a message broker.
2. Use triggers on certain tables to pass messages to a broker on the same machine.

I disliked the first idea due to latency issues which arise when periodical execution of sql is involved.

But event-based trigger approach has a problem which seems unsolvable to me at the moment. Consider this scenario:

1. A row is inserted into a table.
2. Trigger fires and sends a message (using a CLR Stored Procedure written in C#)

Everything is ok unless transaction which writes data is rolled back. In this case data will be consistent, but the message has already been sent and cannot be rolled back because trigger fires at the moment of writing to the database log, not at the time of transaction commit (which is a correct behaviour of a RDBMS).

I realize now that I'm asking too much of triggers and they are not suitable for tasks other than working with data.

So my questions are:

1. Has anyone managed to extract data events using triggers?
2. What other methods of consuming data events can you advise?
3. Is Query Notification (built on top of Service Broker) suitable in my situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're already kind of using SQL Server as a queuing system so maybe some middleware to make that easier: https://docs.particular.net/transports/sql/. There's also a bridge if you want to communicate between SQL Server and RabbitMQ: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lest first cut out of the of the equation the obvious misfit: Query Notification is not right technology for this, because is designed to address cache invalidation of relatively stable data. With QN you'll only know that table has changed, but you won't be able to know *what* had changed.

Kudos to you for figuring out why triggers invoking SQLCRL won't work: the consistency is broken on rollback.

So what *does* work? Consider this: [BizTalk Server](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx). In other words, there is an entire business built around this problem space, and solutions are far from trivial (otherwise nobody would *buy* such products).

You can get quite far though following a few principles:

- **decoupling**. Event based triggers are OK, but do not send the message from the trigger. Aside from the consistency issue on rollback you also have the latency issue of having every DML operation now wait for an external API call (the RabbitMQ send) and the availability issue of the external API call failure (if RabbitMQ is unavailable, your DB is unavailable). The solution is to have the trigger use ordinary [tables as queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), the trigger will enqueue a message in the local db queue (ie. will insert into this table) and and external process will service this queue by dequeueing the messages (ie. delete from the table) and forwarding them to RabbitMQ. This decouples the transaction from the RabbitMQ operation (the external process is able to *see* the message only if the original xact commits), but the cost is some obvious added latency (there is an extra hop involved, the local table acting as a queue).
- **idempotency**. Since RabbitMQ cannot enroll in distributed transactions with the database you cannot guarantee atomicity of the  DB operation (the dequeue from local table acting as queue) and the RabbitMQ operation (the send). Either one can succeed when the other failed, and there is simply no way around it w/o explicit distributed transaction enrollment support. Which implies that the application *will* send duplicate messages every once in a while (usually when things already go bad for some reason). And a quick heads up: enrolling into the act of explicit 'acknowledge' messages and send sequence numbers is a loosing battle as you'll quickly discover that you're reinventing TCP on top of messaging, that road is paved with bodies.
- **tolerance**. For the same reasons as the item above every now in a while a message you believe was sent will never make it. Again, what damage this causes is entirely business specific. The issue is not how to prevent this situation (is almost impossible...) but how to *detect* this situation, and what to do about it. No silver bullet, I'm afraid.

You do mention in passing Service Broker (the fact that is powering Query Notification is the least interestign aspect of it...). As a messaging platform built into SQL Server which offers Exactly Once In Order delivery guarantees and is fully transacted it would solve all the above pain points (you can [`SEND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx) from triggers withouth impunity, you can use [Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to solve the latency issue, you'll never see a duplicate or a missing message, there are clear error semantics) and some other pain points I did not mention before (consistency of backup/restore as the data and the messages are on the same unit of storage - the database, cosnsitnecy of HA/DR failover as SSB support both database mirroring and clustering etc). The draw back though is that SSB is only capable of talking to another SSB service, in other words it can only be used to exchange messages between two (or more) SQL Server instances. Any other use requires the parties to use a SQL Server to exchange messages. But if your endpoints are all SQL Server, then consider that there are some [large scale deployments using Service Broker](http://rusanu.com/2011/06/01/scale-out-sql-server-by-using-reliable-messaging/). Note that endpoints like php or asp.net *can* be considered SQL Server endpoints, they are just programming layers on top of the DB API, a different endpoint would, say, the need to send messages from handheld devices (phones) directly to the database (and eve those 99% of the time go through a web service, which means they can reach a SQL Server ultimately). Another consideration is that SSB is geared toward [throughput](http://rusanu.com/2006/10/16/writing-service-broker-procedures/) and reliable delivery, *not* toward low latency. Is definitely not the technology to use to get back the response in a HTTP web request, for instance. IS the technology to use to submit for processing something triggered by a web request.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer! I came across BizTalk in the first place, but was intimidated by the complexity and price. Now I'm going to try tables as queues approach for simple things, and discuss a possible purchase of BizTalk in the future with my bosses. SSB also needs a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Remus's answer lays out some sound principals for generating and handling events. You can initiate the pushing of events from a trigger to achieve low latency.

You can achieve everything necessary from a trigger. We will still **decouple** this into two components: a trigger that generates the events and a local reader that reads the events.

The first component is the trigger.

- Make a CLR trigger that prepares what needs to be done when the transaction commits.
- Create a `System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification` that always agrees to be prepared, and whose `void Commit(System.Transactions.Enlistment)` method executes the prepared action.
- In the trigger, call `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(enlistmentNotification, System.Transactions.EnlistmentOptions.None)`

You'll want your action to be short and sweet, like appending the data to a lockless queue in memory or updating some other state in memory. Don't try to communicate with other machines or processes. Don't write to a disk (if you wanted to write to a disk, just make an ordinary trigger that inserts into a queue table). You'll need to be careful to make sure your assembly is loaded only once so that any shared static state will be unique; this is easiest to do if your static state is in a top level assembly that isn't referenced by other assemblies, so no other assemblies will try to load it.

You will also need to either

- initialize your state in such a way that it will be correct even if the system was restarted without sending all the previously queued messages (since a short, in memory queue will not be durable). This means you might be resending messages, so they will need to be **idempotent**. or
- rely on the **tolerance** of another component to pick up on missed messages

The second component reads the state that is update by the trigger. Make a separate CLR component that reads from your queue or state, and does whatever you need done (like send an idempotent message to a messaging system, record that it was sent, whatever). If this component can fail (hint: it can), you will need some form of **tolerance**, which may belong in another system. You can achieve low latency by having the trigger signal the second component when new state is available.

One architectural possibility is to have the trigger put the event in memory on commit for another low-latency component to pick up and have the second component send a low-latency, low-reliability copy of an idempotent message. You can pair that with a more reliably or durable messaging system, such as SSB, that will reliably and durably, but with grater latency, send the same idempotent message later.